# Displaying Variables in Text Boxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, object, textbox, html-input

I am trying to make a text box display a value from a property of an object. I want the text box to display the current stock level of an item, e.g:

In the document: *script.js*

```
var shortsF = new Object ( );
shortsF.description = "Stone Wash Denim Shorts";
shortsF.stockLevel = 20;
shortsF.price = 25.9
```

and I would like the textbox "textBox1" on index.html to display shortsF.stockLevel as its default value. e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="textBox1" readOnly="true" value=??? />
```

How is this done?

Comment: This is done by following the instructions in documentation, for example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input. Many other things can also be done by reading the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Put this after you define the `shortsF.stockLevel`

```
document.querySelector('#textBox1').value = shortsF.stockLevel;
```